# Error while accessing insights data of LinkedIn ads manager

Tags: linkedin-api, adsmanager

Below is my Axios post request(Node.js) to LinkedIn for accessing LinkedIn ads manager insights data.

```
LinkedInRouter.get('/getlinkedin', async(req, res) => {
            let response;
             axios.get('https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adCampaignsV2?q=search&fields=id,name,status', {
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
                    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
                    'X-Restli-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0',
                },
            })
            .then(async (resp) => {
                response = resp.data.elements;
                console.log(response);
               
                for (const item of response) {
                    if (item.status === 'ACTIVE') {
                        console.log("Active camp is", item.name);
                        console.log(item);
                        const d = new Date(); // Today!
                        d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1); // Yesterday!
                        const day = d.getDate();
                        const month = d.getMonth() + 1;
                        const year = d.getFullYear();
                                           
                        console.log(day,month,year,item.id);
                        console.log(typeof(day),typeof(month),typeof(year));
                        const date = `${year}-${month}-${day}`
                        console.log(`${date}`);
                        const url = `https://api.linkedin.com/rest/adAnalytics?q=analytics&dateRange.start.month=${month}&dateRange.start.day=${day}&dateRange.start.year=${year}&timeGranularity=DAILY&pivot=CREATIVE&projection=(*,elements*(dateRange(*),reactions,impressions,clicks,likes,shares,follows,costInLocalCurrency,totalEngagements,talentLeads,conversion))&fields=dateRange,reactions,impressions,clicks,likes,shares,follows,costInLocalCurrency,totalEngagements,talentLeads,approximateUniqueImpressions&campaigns=urn:li:sponsoredCampaign:${item.id}`;

                        const resResp = await axios.get(url, {
                            headers: {
                                'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
                                'Linkedin-Version': '202210',
                                'cache-control': 'no-cache',
                                'X-Restli-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0'
                            }
                        })
                        console.log(resResp);
                    }
                    console.log("AFTER API REQST");
                }
                if(response)
                    res.status(200).send("Data Inserted Successfully!")
                else
                    res.status(400).send("Error")
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error.response.data);
                res.status(400).send(error.response.data)
            });   
})
```

when I hit the API, I got an error as follows:

```
{
  status: 400,
  code: 'ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT',
  message: 'Invalid query parameters passed to request'
}
```